# Combine 2 row in Microsoft Access table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I just have a question about importing a table to Access from Excel spreadsheet.

I am basically importing a table from Excel to Access
[image]

And I want the final table to look like this in Access -

[image]

Is this possible in access? or does this need to be modified in Excel before import? If so can I write all of the modification code in Access VBA?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There might be a way to alter the title in Access but it will be much easier if the modification is done in Excel (with code) prior to the import?

Comment: @Flyhigh you can do this pretty simply in Excel VBA or even a simple concatenate formula as well.  Why do you have the requirement of doing this in Access VBA?

Comment: I assume you need this in Access because you are going to do something else with this data once you get it in Access. If not, just do your manipulations in Excel. Following that, does the table structure already exist in Access or are you bringing this in as a new table?

Comment: it was more for convenience factor. i just didnt want to open up 2 programs to just upload data on the database. I want to do it all in Access. Also this is for educational purpose as well. haha

Answer (score -1):

Create a reference to Excel in Access.

In your Access VBA IDE Goto Tools>References and find/add Microsoft Excel ##.# Object Library reference.

You can then declare any variables (with intelliscense!) to Excel objects etc. and do all the required set up through Excel but inside an Access session.

Comment: Don't know why I got a -1 on my answer. The question was; can the Excel manipulation be done in Access. The answer is yes by setting the noted reference. Am I missing something here?